# Is there a book that teaches the main exceptions to English spelling rules?

Tags: english, spelling

I've got books on the rules, now it's exception time!

Comment: Could you please add which variety of English you are interested in? British, American, Australian, Canadian, New Zealand, Indian, ... English? Could you please also add the title of the book you've used so far?